# tkinter multiple windows hierarchy but one icon in taskbar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to open an additional one instance window laying over the main window
and show only the icon of the main window.
I tried already
.transient(), .grab_set(), .wait_window(), .lift(), .focus_force() etc

When I use grab_set() the focus is on second window it prevents more instances 
but the taskbar icon shows the main window. When I minimize all to show desktop there is no chance to maximize the two windows again. I have to kill it then.

How to have only one instance second window but when both lose focus click on taskbar icon 
maximize both with focus on main window ? Second window has to lay on top of the main window not top of all windows. 
Look at video:
https://youtu.be/1mZqpXx9sfw

Comment: That is all I can manage it so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

def on_focus_in_win0(event):
  if win1exist == 1:
    win1.state('normal')
    win1.lift()
  if win2exist == 1:
    win2.state('normal')
    win2.lift()

def on_focus_in_win1(event):
  win0.state('normal')
  win1.state('normal')
  win1.lift()
  if win2exist == 1:
    win2.state('normal')
    win2.lift()


def on_focus_in_win2(event):
  win0.state('normal')
  win1.state('normal')
  win1.lift()
  win2.state('normal') 
  win2.lift()

def destroy_win1(event):
  global win1exist, win2exist
  win1exist = 0
  win2exist = 0
  win2.destroy()   

def show_win1():
  global win1, win1exist

  if win1exist == 1:
    win1.lift()
    win1.after(1, lambda: win1.focus_force())  
    return   

  win1exist = 1
  win1 = Toplevel()   
  win1.geometry("400x400")
  win1.title('win1') 
  win1.lift()
  win1.after(1, lambda: win1.focus_force())  
  win1.bind("<Destroy>", destroy_win1)
  win1.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in_win1)
  but02 = Button(win1, text="Show Win2", fg="black", font="none 15 bold", command=show_win2)
  but02.pack()

def destroy_win2(event):
  global win2exist
  win2exist = 0
  print ( win2exist )

def show_win2():
  global win2, win2exist

  if win2exist == 1:
    win2.lift()
    win2.after(1, lambda: win2.focus_force())  
    return     

  win2exist = 1
  win2 = Toplevel()   
  win2.geometry("300x300")
  win2.title('win2') 
  lab1 = Label(win2, text="Last window", font="none 10 bold")
  lab1.pack()

  win2.lift()
  win2.after(1, lambda: win2.focus_force())  
  win2.bind("<Destroy>", destroy_win2)
  win2.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in_win2)

def task( event ):
  global counter
  counter = counter + 1
  print (counter)  
  win0.state('normal')
  if win1exist == 1:
    win1.state('normal')
  if win2exist == 1:
    win2.state('normal')

win0 = Tk()
win0.title('win0')
win0.geometry("500x500")

win1exist = 0
win2exist = 0

counter = 0;

but01 = Button(win0, text="Show Win1", fg="black", font="none 15 bold", command=show_win1)
but01.pack()
win0.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus_in_win0)
mainloop()
```